# Angular and Laravel Error - App has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am running a project on Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8. When I post login form on angular I got this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/login' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

config/app.php

```
    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

kernel.php

```
    protected $middleware = [
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl:   'http://example.com/api',   
};
```

login.service

```
export class SandboxUserService {

  private API_URL= environment.apiUrl;

  login(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/login', data)
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.SandboxUser.login(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
       error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
  handleResponse(data) {
     this.notify.success('Done, you have successfully logged in.', {timeout:2000, position: "rightTop"})

    this.Token.handle(data.access_token);
    this.Auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
    // this.router.navigateByUrl('/admindashboard');
    if(this.form.id == 1){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/admindashboard');
   }
   else
   {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/userdashboard');
   }
```

After login, I expect it to redirect me to the dashboard. But it did not respond. So when I inspect, I found this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/login' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: You will need to allow CORS in your backend i.e Laravel. You can go through this [article](https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1) on how to allow CORS

Comment: best read up on CORS is you're unfamiliar, it's an important part of dealing with APIs.